# Serialize or separate table for news images?

Tags: php, serialization

I have to add images to a news on my website. I can add from 3 to 10 images. So I was wondering if it were better to put each image in a separate table or just serialize them and put the new string into a column?

Comment: septate table, image_name - news_id. store image on a directory

Comment: That's what I did. Thank you ! :)